# Multiple links web scraping using "rvest" . Error arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: loops, web-scraping, rvest

I was trying rvest web scraping and i go the following error

**Code**

```
library(xml2)


library(rvest)


library(purrr)


ulr_base <- "https://journals.sagepub.com/toc/jina/33/%d"


map_df(1:4,function(i){


 page <- read_html(sprintf(ulr_base,i))


  data.frame(IssueID =html_text(html_nodes(page,".journalNavTitle")),


         Heading = html_text(html_nodes(page,".hlFld-Title")),


         Author = html_text(html_nodes(page,".entryAuthor"))
         
  )


 }) -> SageJournals
```

**Error:**

Error in data.frame(IssueID = html_text(html_nodes(page, ".journalNavTitle")),  :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 6, 65

What should I do now.
note: I use selector gadget.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that you all authors were exported separately. So you had 1 issue, 6 articles, and 65 authors. With these nodes the authors are exported per article:

```
ulr_base <- "https://journals.sagepub.com/toc/jina/33/%d"

map_df(1:4, function(i){
  page <- read_html(sprintf(ulr_base,i))
  data.frame(IssueID = html_text(html_nodes(page,".journalNavTitle")),
             Heading = html_text(html_nodes(page, ".heading-title")),
             Author = html_text(html_nodes(page, ".all"))
  )
}) -> SageJournals
```